# Валидация формы телефона php и отправка на почту

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, форма, валидация, отправка

Есть код для отправки номера телефона на почту php+ajax. Как добавить в php валидацию через регулярное выражение??

```
<?php
$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
if($post) {
$email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));
$name = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name']));
$sub = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["sub"]));
$message = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['message']));
$error = '';
if(!$name) {$error .= 'Укажите свое имя. ';}
if(!$email) {$error .= 'Укажите электронную почту. ';}
if(!$sub) {$error .= 'Укажите тему обращения. ';}
if(!$message || strlen($message) < 1) {$error .= 'Введите сообщение. ';}
if(!$error) {
    $address = "primer@example.ru";
    $mes = "Почта: ".$email."\n\nИмя: ".$name."\n\nТема: " 
.$sub."\n\nСообщение: ".$message."\n\n";
    $send = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = 
UTF-8\r\nReply-To:$email\r\nFrom:$name <contact>");
    if($send) {echo 'OK';}
}
else {echo '<div class="err">'.$error.'</div>';}
}
?>
```

Comment: А где сам формат номера телефона?

Comment: ^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$     https://habrahabr.ru/post/110731/

Answer (score 0):

Из простого - нет разделителей, начало на `+380` (Украина):

```
$phone = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['phone']));
$pattern = "/^\+380\d{9}$/";
if(!preg_match($pattern, $phone)) {$error .= 'Номер телефона не соответствует формату';}
```

В месте сбора почтового сообщения:

```
$mes .= 'Номер телефона: '.$phone.'\n\n';
```

**UPD**

[online tests](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/nH6)

Comment: Почему то не срабатывает, проходит мимо проверки и отправляет письмо.

Comment: '<?php
$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
if($post) {
 $tel = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['tel']));
 $error = '';
 if(!$tel) {$error .= 'Укажите свое имя. ';}
 if(!$error) {
  $address = "xxxx@mail.ru";

Comment: $pattern = "^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$";
  if(!preg_match($pattern, $tel)) {$error .= 'Номер телефона не соответствует формату';}
  $mes = "Телефон: ".$tel."\n\n";
  $sub ="Форма\x02отправки\x02телефона";
  $send = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = UTF-8\r\nReply-To:$email\r\nFrom:$name <contact>");
  if($send) {echo 'OK';}
 }
 else {echo '<div class="err">'.$error.'</div>';}
}
?>'

Comment: Тесты для `"/^\+380\d{9}$/"` (http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/nH6). Пробуйте подброс значений для `^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$`. Какой номер телефона пытаетесь отправить?

Comment: +79261234567
89261234567
79261234567
+7 926 123 45 67
8(926)123-45-67
123-45-67
9261234567
79261234567
(495)1234567
(495) 123 45 67
89261234567
8-926-123-45-67
8 927 1234 234
8 927 12 12 888
8 927 12 555 12
8 927 123 8 123

Comment: он кушает все это, я пытался банально отправить %9182311414 к примеру и он все равно съел и прислал это на почту

Comment: попробовал вашу регулярку 380№435345 все равно отправил, ошибка не в регулярка, а где то в логике в коде, не срабатывает проверка(

Comment: Определитесь с форматом номера телефона, который Вам нужно получать с запроса. Чем больше форматов номеров телефона, тем сложнее будет регулярное выражение

Comment: `380№435345` - не пропускает. (http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/nHa, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/60c5b975e243cd1bc44cb25de1fd2a43ef934684)

Comment: ^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$ эта же регулярка на стороне клиента работает без проблем, в вот в пхп проблема(